# How do I enable multisampling using glfw in Python?

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

I am trying to enable 4x multisampling for OpenGL in Python. But I keep getting an error saying "GFLW_SAMPLES" is not defined. The way I understand it this should be included in glfw.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
import glfw
import sys

glfw.window_hint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4)
```

Is there another library I have to import for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

```py
import glfw

glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 4)
```

or

```py
from glfw.GLFW import *

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4)
```